# Parallel video transcoding using hardware acceleration

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I'm trying to simultaneously transcode multiple videos using `ffmpeg`. I do see substantial speed gain when using GPU on a single video file. When transcoding a single file the GPU load is quite low (about 15%), so I thought that I could run several processes in parallel. But running even two transcoding tasks in parallel takes almost 2x time. Why parallelization does not work?

I'm using AWS g4dn.2xlarge instance with Tesla T4 GPU and running a simple command like

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -y -i src.mkv -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 300k out.mp4
```

Any help/insights on how to accelerate massive video transcoding is greatly appreciated.

Comment: After digging into it I've found that NVidia chips use dedicated hardware decoder and encoder blocks, and don't use GPU cores for video transcoding. Tesla T4 has an encoder capable of processing only a single video stream.